# Kali linux stuck on boot

Tags: linux, kali-linux

```
/dev/sda5: clean, 673046/6914048 files, 6428354/27648000 blocks
[  OK  ] Finished Tell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data.
[  OK  ] Reached target System Initialization.
[  OK  ] Started Daily apt download activities.
[  OK  ] Started Daily apt upgrade and clean activities.
[  OK  ] Started Periodic ext4 Online Metadata Check for All Filesystems.
[  OK  ] Started Discard unused blocks ones a week.
[  OK  ] Started Refresh fwupd metadata regularly.
[  OK  ] Started Weekly GeoIP update.
[  OK  ] Started Daily rotation of log files.
[  OK  ] Started Daily timer for the Lymis security audit and vulnerability scanner.
[  OK  ] Started Daily man-db regeneration.
[  OK  ] Started Updates mlocate database every day.
[  OK  ] Started Clean PHP session files every 30 mins.
[  OK  ] Started Daily Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
[  OK  ] Reached target Timers.
[  OK  ] Listening on D-Bus System Message Bus Socket.
[  OK  ] Listening on PS/SC Smart Card Daemon Activation Socket.
[  OK  ] Listening on UUID daemon activation socket.
[  OK  ] Reached target Sockets.
[  OK  ] Reached target Basic System.
         Starting Accounts Service...
[  OK  ] Started Regular background program processing daemon.
[  OK  ] Started D-Bus System Message Bus.
         Starting Network Manager...
         Starting Remove Stale Online ext4 Metadata Check Snapshots...
[  OK  ] Reached target Login Prompts.
         Starting LSB: GNU Network Utilities internet superserver...
         Starting Authorization Manager...
         Starting System Logging Service...
         Starting Self Monitoring and Reporting Technology (SMART) Daemon...
         Starting LSB: Start or stop stunnel 4.x (TLS tunnel for network daemons)...
         Starting User Login Management...
         Starting LSB: thin initscript...
         Starting Anonymizing overlay network for TCP (multi-instance-master)...
         Starting Weekly GeoIP update...
         Starting Clean PHP session files...
         Starting Rotate log files...
         Starting Daily man-db regenaration...
[  OK  ] Started Update a database for mlocate.
[  OK  ] Finished Anonymizing overlay network for TCP (multi-instance-master).
[ INFO ] Skipped Weekly GeoIP update.
[  OK  ] Started LSB: Start or stop stunnel 4.x (TLS tunnel for network daemons).
[  OK  ] Started LSB: GNU Network Utilities internet superserver.
[  OK  ] Finished Remove Stale Online ext4 Metadata Check Snapshots.
[  OK  ] Started Self Monitoring and Reporting Technology (SMART) Daemon.
[FAILED] Failed to start Starting 4nonimizer.ilesystem checks in progress
```

Comment: Kali is an OS that can be tricky to set up in some instances, and isn't really suited well to beginners. That being said, what have you tried so far to resolve the issue?

Comment: `Reached target Login Prompts` indicates that you should be able to log on to the virtual terminals and explore what might cause the hang. The `FAILED` line is obviously of high interest; I suppose its content changes regularly, and you copied it at a moment when two (or more?) outputs were mashed together. Can you untangle it?

Comment: A boot log without any kind of context isn't very useful. Has this setup worked for you prior? If so, what did you change? If no, how did you install and what were you trying to do